# HTML5 table row adding data dynamically

Tags: html, cordova, html-table, tablerow

I creating an application in phonegap where I am displaying the date of birth details of a person from database w. And details are stored in localstorage.. But when I a trying to display the details inside a table it is not working.. If any body can help .. please help.. I am giving my code below..

```
</head> 
<body onload="onLoad();">    
<div class="app">
<label id="naming">Saved Data</label>
<br>
<br>
<table id="myTable" border="1" style="width:100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Full details</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr id="first">
    <td>First Name</td>   
     <td id="tbfn">First Name</td>   
  </tr>
<tr id="middle">
    <td>Middle Name</td>
    <td ></td>         
  </tr>
<tr id="last">
    <td>Last Name</td> 
    <td ></td>        
  </tr>
<tr id="day">
    <td>Day of birth</td>
    <td></td>         
  </tr>
<tr id="month">
    <td>Month of Birth</td> 
    <td></td>        
  </tr>
<tr id="year">
    <td>Year of Birth</td> 
    <td></td>        
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  app.initialize();
function onLoad() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");   
   document.getElementById("tbfn").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('fnm');
}
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you get any error in your JS console?

Comment: I assume that since you have a database you have many names stored.You have to use a for loop

Comment: Actually... local storage only one value can be saved and I am storing it in another page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you replace `localStorage.getItem('fnm')` with a simple string, this works perfectly

```
document.getElementById("tbfn").innerHTML = 'John';
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9xum9hb/)

So, the problem is with the localStorage not being filled in the other page. This means, you must check the value of `fnm`, e.g.

```
var fnm = localStorage.getItem('fnm');
console.log('fnm=' + fnm);
```

and look for errors in the other page, where the value should be set.

Comment: Thanks Olaf... the problem was with insertion of data to localstorage... Thanks....